# Netty Epoll linking issue - wrong ELF class

Tags: arm, netty, epoll

I was wondering if anyone has been able to successfully use the Netty Epoll native transports on an ARM based Debian distribution?  I have downloaded the netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.1.Final-20160526.120605-1.jar file and placed it in my class path, however when I attempt to run my app I get the following error:

```
    Java HotSpot(TM) Embedded Client VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll2335866969247669919.so which might have disabled stack guard. 
    The VM will try to fix the stack guard now. It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
    /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll2335866969247669919.so: /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll2335866969247669919.so: 
    wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
    at java.la`
```

I saw a post earlier that spoke to using the pure java implementation and that is what I thought I was using but based on the ELFCLASS64 message I can only ascertain that I am not.

I have followed the instructions on the Netty native-transports page and have successfully compiled the code in Netbeans, but I still get the same message.  Do I need to compile on the ARM platform directly?

I would appreciate any help/insight that anyone can provide. And by all means, if I need to provide more information just ask and I will respond.

Thanks so much in advance...

- Tim

Comment: Hi, any update? Did you get it compiled?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to compile it on the ARM system directly if you can find an option in the compiler you're using to [cross compile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) the native transport targeting your ARM architecture. Otherwise you will need to compile it on the ARM system directly or find someone that already has done so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we support ARM. We only compile for x86_64